# Parsing JSON in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using JSON in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775542/using-json-in-ios)

How does one parse JSON response in iOS? I have found this [tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/), and followed it but don't understand the exact way to do this. So, can anyone please give me a perfect tutorial about the using JSON library.

Comment: Also [iPhone/iOS JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial), [Comparison of JSON Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256625/), [Parse JSON in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992487/), and [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+%5Bjson%5D+tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing JSON in iOS is very easy with the [SBJson library](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/), and a frequent question on SO.

Quickly though, there are only two methods you should need in the SBJson library, `-JSONValue` and `-JSONRepresentation`:

- `-JSONValue` cane be called on any `NSString` of JSON, once the library has been added to your project, and returns an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` based on that JSON.
- `-JSONRepresentation` called on an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` returns the JSON-string representation of that object...really straightforward.

For more information, please see my examples [in this duplicate question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986616/how-to-parse-the-result-returned-by-google-geo-coding-api-in-objective-c/6986675#6986675).

Comment: thanks GarlicFries.. your answer works.. Can you explain me about this negative reputation on Stackoverflow question..?

Comment: While I did not do so, your question was likely downvoted because it is a duplicate of many other questions on StackOverflow.  It's important to have a look around and see if other people have already asked what you are about to ask before you do so, as asking duplicate questions is also just asking for a downvote.